# Indexing a sub-array by lists

Tags: numpy, indexing

I have some array `A` and 2 lists of indices `ind1` and `ind2`, one for each axis. Now this gives me a slice of the array, to which I need to assign some new values. Problem is, my approach for this does not work.

Let me demonstrate with an example. First I create an array, and try to access some slice:

```
>>> A=numpy.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> ind1, ind2 = [0,1], [1,2]
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> A[ind1,ind2]
array([1, 5])
```

Now this just gives me 2 values, not the 2-by-2 matrix I was going for. So I tried this:

```
>>> A[ind1,:][:,ind2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

Okay, better. Now let's say these value should be 0:

```
>>> A[ind1,:][:,ind2]=0
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

If I try to assign like this, the array `A` does not get updated, because   of the double indexing (I am only assigning to some copy of `A`, which gets discarded). Is there some way to index the sub array by just indexing once?

Note: Indexing by selecting some appropriate range like `A[:2,1:3]` would work for this example, but I need something that works with any arbitrary list of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to create your 2d-indexes? As follows

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> ind1, ind2 = [0,1],[1,2]
>>> ind12 = np.meshgrid(ind1,ind2, indexing='ij')
>>> #     = np.ix_(ind1,ind2) as pointed out by @Divakar
>>> A[ind12]
[[1 2]
 [4 5]]
```

And finally

```
>>> A[ind12] = 0
>>> A
[[0 0 0]
 [3 0 0]
 [6 7 8]]
```

*Which works with any arbitrary list of indices.*

```
>>> ind1, ind2 = [0,2],[0,2]
>>> ind12 = np.meshgrid(ind1,ind2, indexing='ij')
>>> A[ind12] = 100
[[100   1 100]
 [  3   4   5]
 [100   7 100]]
```

---

As pointed out by @hpaulj in comments, note that [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html)`(ind1,ind2)` is actually equivalent to the following use of `np.meshgrid`,

```
>>> np.meshgrid(ind1,ind2, indexing='ij', sparse=True)
```

Which is *a priori* even more efficient. This is a major point in the `np.ix_`'s favor when the parameters `indexing` and `sparse` are constantly set to `'ij'` and `True` respectively.

Comment: I believe OP is kind of vague in this sense, but I believe for your second example should result in a zero array (such that the `ind1` and `ind2` entries define a slice matrix, e.g. by spanned by two ranges (row and column width), not a list of matching specific indices). Or maybe I'm the one that have understood it in the wrong way.

Comment: @dfri Anyway Divakar agrees with my understanding since the duplicate he points to gives exactly the same output as mine. That being said, this does not mean you are not right. Which in turn would mean that this question is actually not a duplicate.

Comment: No, I was looking for this behavior. So this makes the question is a duplicate ...

Comment: Then it's sorted out!

Comment: I would use `np.ix_(ind1, ind2)` rather than `meshgrid`.  It produces the same thing as `np.meshgrid(..., sparse=True)`.